# NTFS mount issue in Lion

Tags: macos, ntfs

I am getting this error. Can anybody help me?

/Library/Filesystems/fusefs.fs/Support/fusefs.kext failed to load - (libkern/kext) requested architecture/executable not found;

Comment: http://handyrandy.tumblr.com/post/279850663 - perhaps this could help?

Comment: FYI, you'll not be able to share a drive using other format than HFS+ on Lion, send my thanks to Apple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to upgrade to a new version of MacFuse. Unfortunately there isn't one available. See this [blog post](http://www.offthehill.org/articles/2010/12/31/macfuse-for-64-bit-snow-leopard/). So there is a new project called [OSXFuse](https://github.com/osxfuse) which is going to support this. Here is the link to the Github project. https://github.com/osxfuse

I hope this helps a little.

Answer (score 0):

Check [Fuse4X project](http://fuse4x.org), it should help you. Here is another [lengthy article](http://fernandoff.posterous.com/ntfs-write-support-on-osx-lion-with-ntfs-3g-f) about current state of NTFS on OSX.

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone.